# jQuery detecting elements added via ajax

Tags: jquery

The following does not respond when a select field with class='crit' is inserted in to the page via ajax once the page has loaded, and is then changed. How can I make it do so?

```
$(".crit").click(function(){alert("hello")})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('.crit').live('click', function(e) {
    alert('hello');
});
```

A regular event is only bound to the currently existing elements. When using [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) the event handler is bound to the document itself and thanks to event bubbling it doesn't no handlers have to be attached to the actual elements.